# Disconnect the VPN that other apps have enabled in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, vpn, openvpn, android-vpn-service

Is there a way to disconnect any VPN connection on the Android device?
My app uses Wi-Fi Direct to establish a P2P connection with other devices. On some devices, Wi-Fi Direct does not work when the VPN is active, and I want to disconnect any VPN connection that is enabled on the device.
I tried this code and was able to do so. But using this, the user is asked for permission to access the VPN and then a VPN connection is created with the name of my app. So I do not want to use this code.

```
startActivityForResult(VpnService.prepare(this), 0);
```

If there is no way to disconnect, how can the user be redirected to the VPN settings page to do so manually?

Comment: "Is there a way to disconnect any VPN connection on the Android device?" -- I hope not, except perhaps for device owner apps. "how can the user be redirected to the VPN settings page to do so manually?" -- on API Level 24 and higher, [start an `ACTION_VPN_SETTINGS` activity](
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_VPN_SETTINGS).

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. But I think it is possible. Some applications that create a VPN connection first disconnect the previous VPN connection and then establish their own connection.

Comment: Yes, and that is the one valid scenario for it. However, you do not appear to be writing a VPN app. And, you already know how to accomplish that -- it is in your question. You seem to be seeking to have a random other app be able to unilaterally tear down the VPN connection, and that hopefully is not possible except perhaps via device owner (or I guess device admin) apps.